# Assigning value to Search Bar Delegate - Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, search

So I was following [this](http://shrikar.com/swift-ios-tutorial-uisearchbar-and-uisearchbardelegate/) link for implementing a Search Bar in my Table View.

I had to make a few changes because my cells contained Objects with different values and data types and so I had to adapt the Search function accordingly.

I'm pretty sure I have most of it working, I just have 2 questions.

- On creating the variable representing the UI Table View being used, notice (in the link) that he calls the variable `tableView` (at the top of script). Would this interfere with the rest of the tableView variables used in the many functions in the class? Does it not act as a global variable, affecting others of the same name in his class?
- I receive the error `Cannot assign a value of type '...ViewController' to a value of type 'UISearchBarDelegate'` on the line `searchBar.delegate = self`
  It seems to me like this is the only error I have and everything else is fine. So what is wrong here, and how might I go about fixing it? Have I made a mistake somewhere or is the mistake in the link?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no problem with the use of `tableView` as both a local (to a function) and "global" variable name.  If you have a local and a global variable with the same name, the code will access the local variable in preference to the global.  If you want to access the global, you would have to code it as `self.tableView`.

As regards your error, note that in the tutorial's class definition:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate, UISearchBarDelegate
```

it specifies `UISearchBarDelegate`, to indicate that the class adopts that protocol.  The error you are getting suggests you have missed this step.